# How to make a particular div selectable(copy/paste) using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Does anyone know how to make particular div selectable(copy/paste) using javascript when we already have `onselectstart="return false;"` in html page

```
    <head>
           <script type="text/javascript">              

                function DisableSelection(){
                    var srcType = event ? ( event.srcElement ? event.srcElement.tagName: null ) : null;
                        if(srcType && ( srcType == "text" || srcType == "textarea" ) )
                        {
                        return true;
                        }
                    return false;

                    }

            </script>
    </head>

<body onContextMenu="return false" onselectstart="return DisableSelection();"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[DIV].onselectstart="";
[DIV].oncontextmenu="";
```

**Edit**:

Just realized that this may be your page...

```
function canSelect(e)
{
    e=e?e:event;
    if(e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
    else e.cancelBubble=true;
    return true;
}
```

And then use

```
[DIV].onselectstart=canSelect;
```

or

```
<div onselectstart="return canSelect(event);">
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.. I try this things to but not worked..as u see here in html page "return false;"..so all the things in body are already unselectable. Now I have to make particular div(dynamically created in javascript) selectable.Please help me out..